# Cancel all stacked notifications in Android Wear

Tags: java, android, notifications, wear-os

I've been playing a little with the stacked notifications in Android Wear (http://developer.android.com/training/wearables/notifications/stacks.html) but I have a little issue.

In my application I want to show a notification at a given time and then cancel it 2 hours later. On a classic Android notification I use `notificationManager.cancel(NotifId)` but as each stacked notification has it's own id I wonder if only cancelling the summary notification if enough or if I have to cancel all of them explicitly.

Do you have any idea ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can confirm that by dismissing the summary notification on the phone, you also dismiss the entire stack of notifications on the watch. Furthermore, you can also swipe to dismiss the entire stack on the watch, which will in turn dismiss the summary notification on the phone.

However, these two actions are not 100% identical. For example, if you set a `deleteIntent` for stacked wearable notification, it is not automatically applied to the summary notification on the phone. So if you dismiss the notification from the watch, that `PendingIntent` will be triggered, as one might expect. However, if you dismiss the summary notification from the phone, then that `PendingIntent` will not be triggered, even though the stacked notification is removed from the watch.